# need help about print a list in a for loop

Tags: python

I've created a function called "list_product():" and trying to print a dictionary inside of a list using for loops, but it prints me out 4 rows instead of 1. The same quantity of the inputs

```
productos=[{'ID':1,'Producto':'Soda','Quantity':3,'Price':12.4}]
def list_product():
    print("\nid | product | quantity | price")
    print("*"*50)
    for products in productos: 
        for elem in products:
            print(f"{products['ID']} | {products['Producto']} | {products['Quantity']} | {products['Price']}")
```

```
1 | Soda | 3 | 12.4
1 | Soda | 3 | 12.4
1 | Soda | 3 | 12.4
1 | Soda | 3 | 12.4
```

I expect the output of this to be just a row, I'm still trying to solve this. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre]. For example in this code, `Soda` and `productos` are not defined, which prevents others from reproducing the problem. Edit: Looks like they were just typos, eh?

Comment: @wjandrea I fixed them for the OP, but you were right. It is still common courtesy to double check if your example compiles at the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the second (inner) `for`. You are already selecting elements by key, so you don't need nested loops:

```
for products in productos: 
    print(f"{products['ID']} | {products['Producto']} | {products['Quantity']} | {products['Price']}")
```

A side effect of using nested loops is that dictionaries are either unordered (pre-Python 3.7) or in creation order (>=3.7). That makes it harder to keep the same column order in the output.